# How can I get the variable value I need

Tags: php, mysql, forms, list, variables

how can I get the variable value I need, I have selected comments and like values through MySQL and have created a like button, but when I click like, it adds the like to the last selected/posted variable value, so it likes the last comment generated.  How to I get it to like the one I wanted and not the last selected?

Example:

I have comments with id's (1,2,3) when generated it orders them in that order (1,2,3) when I like comment with id=2 it likes comment 3 because it was last generated so the varible id has a value of 3 at the time I liked comment 2.

I don't make any sense, I hope you guys get it, please help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note.php

```
//-------- WHILE LOOP FOR GETTING NOTE COMMENTS -------

$commentsList = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM note_comments WHERE note_id='$note_id'");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) != false) {
    $commentsList[] = array(
        'comId' => $row['id'],
        'comment' => $row['comment'],
        'com_likes' => $row['likes'],
        'com_likers' => $row['likers']
    );
}
```

note.php (body):

```
        <div id="noteComments">
        <h2>Comments</h2>
        <?php 
        $commentL = $commentsList;
        if (count($commentL) == 0) {
            echo 'Sorry, there are no comments.';
        } else {
            echo '<ul style="list-style:none;">';
            foreach($commentL as $comment) {
                echo '<li><p>', $comment['comment'], '</p><p><a style="background-color:#3b3c3b; color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none; padding: 1 5 1 5; border-radius:5px; border: 1px solid black; " href="#" onclick="like_add(', $comment['comId'] ,');">Like</a><span id="comment_', $comment['comId'] ,'_likes">', $comment['com_likes'] , '</span> like this</p></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        ?>
        </div><!-- end noteComments -->
```

---

like.js

```
function like_add(comId) {
$.post('ajax/like_add.php', {comId:comId}, function(data) {
    if (data == 'success') {
        like_get(comId);
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
}); 
}

function like_get(comId) {
$.post('ajax/like_get.php', {comId:comId}, function(data) {
    $('#comment_'+comId+'_likes').text(data);
});
}
```

---

like_add.php

```
<?php
include_once("../scripts/checkuserlog.php");
include '../functions/like.php';
if (isset($_POST['comId']) && comment_exists($_POST['comId'])) {
$comId = $_POST['comId'];
add_like($comId);
}
?>
```

like_get.php

```
<?php
include '../scripts/checkuserlog.php';
include '../functions/like.php';
if (isset($_POST['comId']) && comment_exists($_POST['comId'])) {
echo like_count($_POST['comId']);
}
?>
```

---

like.php

```
<?php
function comment_exists($comId) {
$comId = (int)$comId;
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM note_comments WHERE id=$comId"), 0) == 0) ? false : true;
}

function like_count($comId) {
$comId = (int)$comId;
return (int)mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT likes FROM note_comments WHERE id=$comId"), 0, 'likes');
}
function add_like($comId) {
$comId = (int)$comId;
$visitor = $_SESSION['id'];
$com_likers = "";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT likes, likers FROM note_comments WHERE id='$comId'");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) != false) {

        $com_likes = $row['likes'];
        $com_likers = $row['likers'];
} 
$thisComlikers = explode(",", $com_likers);
if (!in_array($visitor, $thisComlikers)) {
    if ($com_likers != "") { $com_likers = "$com_likers,$visitor"; } else { $com_likers = "$visitor"; }

mysql_query("UPDATE note_comments SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id=$comId")or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("UPDATE note_comments SET likers =$com_likers WHERE id=$comId")or die (mysql_error());
echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'You have already liked this!';
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have three comments all on the same post:

First Table: comments

```
id | post_id | comment
1  | 1       | "something"
2  | 1       | "something else"
3  | 1       | "something else entirely"
```

Second Table: comment_likes

```
id | comment_id
1  | 2
2  | 2
3  | 3
```

In this example, comment 2 would have 2 likes, and comment 3 one.

This might be the code to show our comments. The trick here is to add a custom attribute to the like link so we can detect the comment id in javascript.

```
<div class="comments">
<?php
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = '.$post_id.';');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $cid = $row['id'];
    echo '<div class="comment">';
    echo $row['comment'].'<br />';
    echo '<span class="like" comment-id="'.$cid.'">Like</span>';
    $lres = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comment_likes` WHERE `comment_id` = '.$cid.';');
    $likes = mysql_result($lres,0);

    echo '<span class="likes">';
    if ($likes > 0) {
        echo '<span class="num_likes">'.$likes.'</span>';
        $p = ($likes > 1) ? 'people like' : 'person likes';
        echo $likes.' '.$p.' this';

    }
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Now the JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.like').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('comment-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add_like.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {'id':id},
            success: function(res) {
                if (res === '1') {
                   var likes = $('.like[comment-id='+id+']').find('.num_likes').text();
                   likes++;
                   var p = likes > 1 ? 'people like' : 'person likes';
                   var html = '<span class="num_likes">'+likes+'</span> '+p+' this';
                   $('.like[comment-id='+id+']').find('likes').html(html);
                }
                else alert('Error Liking Comment');
            },
            error: function() { alert('Error liking comment'); }
        });
    });  
});
```

And the PHP (for the AJAX) - **add_like.php**

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['id'])) exit;
$id = $_POST['id'];
// connect / select db
$res = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `comment_likes` WHERE `comment_id` = '.$id.';');
if ($res) {
    die(1); // success
}
die(0);

?>
```

Obviously you'd want to expand this for liking/un-liking - because at the moment the user can like multiple times but you get the idea.

Comment: that is my problem it likes the wrong comment, it posts the right number of likes for each comment but you can't like it.

Comment: I have asked this question once before but didn't get any response you can see all of my problem code by going to "when I click on my like button it likes the top comment not the one I wanted?" thank you for helping, and please don't stop (that's what everyone else does)

Comment: does span like need to have a link, does like need to be a link

Comment: @AustinWheeler you can make it an anchor if you like, or you could just apply css to `.like`

Comment: I can't get this function to work?                                 function comment_exists($comId) {
 $comId = (int)$comId;
 return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM note_comments WHERE id=$comId"), 0) == 0) ? false : true;
}

Comment: include '../functions/like.php';
if (isset($_POST['comId']) && comment_exists($_POST['comId'])) {
 echo 'works';
}

Comment: it says its giving a Boolean instead of a resource

Comment: it means your query is failing - try COUNT(*) for a start

Comment: okay, my like button works, but the ajax is really slow, so it takes a couple of seconds before the like count is updated, is there a way to speed it up.

Comment: @AustinWheeler what you might want to do is do what stack overflow do and update the count for the user and then send the AJAX off, and reverting it if there is an error

Comment: it also sends me too the top of the page

Comment: what sends you to the top of the page? - please be more specific - also I can't help you with every little problem you have please try and do stuff for yourself